# class attribute messup in chrome

Tags: php, html, css, variables

My php foreach code is like bellow

```
 echo "<ul>";
        foreach($value as $key1 => $subjects){

        echo  "<li><span class='add-on'>$subjects</span>
       <input type='text' class={$subjects}  name={$key1}/></li>" ;

        }
  echo "</ul>";
```

This html output should be return like bellow

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span class='add-on'>Something</span>
  <input type='text' class=" "  name="Something"/>
</li>
</ul>
```

But what i get the output like bellow from firebug

```
<ul>
<li>
<span class="add-on"></span>
<input type="text" class="name=primary_enviornment/">
</li>
</ul>
```

**NOTE:some  $subjects values contaisn NULL values.it's ok**

So why this happened

`<input type="text" class="name=primary_enviornment/">`
`<!--See the class attribute -->`

Comment: `foreach($subjects as $key1 => $value)`

Comment: no.$value coming from another foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `"` around your attributes and concatenate strings using `.` operator. The double quotes around the attribute values are escaped using the backslash `\`:

```
foreach($value as $key1 => $subjects){

    echo  "<li><span class='add-on'>$subjects</span>
   <input type='text' class=\"".$subjects."\"  name=\"".$key1."\"/></li>" ;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing quotes around your attributes try this.

```
echo  "<li><span class='add-on'>",$subjects,"</span><input type='text' class='",$subjects,"'  name='",$key1,"'/></li>" ;;
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in

Comment: @TirupathiRaju This use case comma's are preferred over concatenation. slightly smaller memory usage as it doesn't have to keep the string in memory just flush it out. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php

Comment: @DiliniWasana - $subjects," '- place this near name